# Why does my redhat 5.11 system have so many ext4-dio-unwrit processes?

Tags: rhel, process

I have a redhat 5.11 system running, and it looks like there are 32 of these processes.

What are they, and why are there so many of them?

Comment: A web search for ext4-dio-unwrit returns lots of relevant stuff - seems this is normal

Comment: ya, but most of the answers are either locked up (i.e. log in with RHN credentials) or just "that's normal".  I figure that if there's not an answer in the first page of google pointing to a stack exchange site, I should ask the question here.